# how to call method in one application from another application in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call the method and get the response in my application from another application in Ruby on Rails technology, but here cross site scripting problem is there. so, i can i resolve this issue please help me it would be great.

http://video_tok.com/courses/get_course

```
def get_course
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end
```

now i want to call this above method from this application which is running in edupdu.com domain

http://edupdu.com/call_course_method

```
def call_course_method
  @course = redirect_to "http://video_tak.com/courses/get_course/1"
end
```

but it would be redirect into video_tak.com application.
i want to call get_course method and get @course object internally without redirect to another site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: You could fetch the courses via JSON(P)

Answer (score 3):

Cross-domain AJAX is indeed a problem, but none that could not be solved. In your `get_course` method you could return the course objects as a JSON response like so:

```
render json: @course
```

From there on you could either retrieve the course through JavaScript (AJAX), here you should use JSONP or inside Rails by issuing a HTTP GET request.

1. AJAX with JSONP

   There is JSONP (JSON with padding), which is a communication technique for JavaScript programs to provide a method to request data from a server in a different domain. Look at 
   the documentation of [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and scroll down to the JSONP section.

   > If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` (or similar, as defined by
   >   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
   >   discussion of the `jsonp` data type in `$.ajax()` for more details.
2. HTTP GET request

   Simply use the `Net::HTTP` class:

   ```
   require 'net/http'
   require 'json'

   url = URI.parse('http://video_tak.com/courses/get_course/1')
   req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
   res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
     http.request(req)
   end
   course_json = JSON.parse(res.body)
   ```

   If you provide methods for your model to convert JSON into a domain object of yours, you can take it from there.

---

**RPC**

You can also use RPC to invoke methods between different Ruby processes, although I recommend this the least I do not want to omit it. There are several remote procedure call (RPC) libraries. The Ruby standard library provides [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html), but there are also implementations based on Ruby on Rails, for instance the [rails-xmlrpc](https://github.com/alexkv/rails-xmlrpc) gem which allows you to implement RPC based on the [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) protocol or the alternative protocol using JSON with  [json-rpcj](https://github.com/PeterBengtson/json-rpc-1-1)

You will probably find even more libraries when searching for *Rails RPC*. From whatever library you pick, the concrete solution will differ.